# How to refresh page elements with jQuery, json, and php

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to refresh several sections of a page every 10 seconds or so with data being pulled from a php file. I think I'm close but I'm getting this error: ReferenceError: Can't find variable: a

```
// roster.php

$a = "some a data...";
$b = "some b data...";
$c = "some c data...";

$data['a'] = $a;
$data['b'] = $b;
$data['c'] = $c;
echo json_encode($data);

//html

<div id="div-a"></div>
<div id="div-b"></div>
<div id="div-c"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() { 

        function loadPage(){

            var a = "";
            var b = "";
            var c = "";

            $.getJSON('roster2.php', function(data) {
                a = data.a;
                b = data.b;
                c = data.c;
            });

            alert("a: "+a);// for testing
            alert("b: "+b);// for testing
            alert("c: "+c);// for testing

            jQuery('#div-a').html(a);
            jQuery('#div-b').html(b);
            jQuery('#div-c').html(c);
        }

        loadPage(); // This will run on page load
        setInterval(function(){
            loadPage() // this will run after every 5 seconds
        }, 8000);

    }); //ready(function
</script
```

any idea?

Comment: "You are ordering a Pizza, then are trying to eat if before it is delivered". basically the getJSON is asynchronous and calls back long after your alerts fire.

Comment: You should put the `alert()` and `jQuery.html()` portions inside the `.done()` event of `getJSON` (or as TrueBlueAussie says, you're trying to set the values before they have arrived).  Also, you can use `$` instead of `jQuery` when you set the HTML contents, I don't know why you're mixing (they refer to the same object, but why use both?).

Answer (score 0):

You need to make use of the async nature of `getJSON`. The values do not exist until the callback fires "sometime later" after it was called.

Move your code inside the callback.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() { 

        function loadPage(){

            var a = "";
            var b = "";
            var c = "";

            $.getJSON('roster2.php', function(data) {
                a = data.a;
                b = data.b;
                c = data.c;
                alert("a: "+a);// for testing
                alert("b: "+b);// for testing
                alert("c: "+c);// for testing

                $('#div-a').html(a);
                $('#div-b').html(b);
                $('#div-c').html(c);
            });

        }

        loadPage(); // This will run on page load
        setInterval(function(){
            loadPage() // this will run after every 5 seconds
        }, 8000);

    }); //ready(function
</script
```

As far as the mixed use of jQuery and $ goes, pick one :)

The simplest/safest solution is to use this shortcut DOM ready handler:

```
jQuery(function($){
     // Your code goes here using a locally scoped $
});
```

This does the same as `jQuery(document).ready(function(){})` but is short and provides the jQuery object as the first parameter.

Answer (score 0):

TrueBlueAussie is correct in what he's telling you to do, but he's done it wrong.  See [the documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/).

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        loadPage(); // This will run on page load
        setInterval(function(){
            loadPage() // this will run after every *8* seconds
        }, 8000);

    }); //ready function

    //moved this function outside the ready function.
    //there's no need for it to be contained within.
    function loadPage(){

        $.getJSON('roster2.php', function(data) {
            //this method is called to SEND data to the PHP page
            //this is the mistake that TrueBlueAussie has made
        })
        .done(function(data) {
            //this method is called when the data comes BACK
            alert("a: "+data.a);// for testing
            alert("b: "+data.b);// for testing
            alert("c: "+data.c);// for testing

            $('#div-a').html(data.a);
            $('#div-b').html(data.b);
            $('#div-c').html(data.c);
        });
    }
</script>
```